# cql filter do not work on mongodb store layers in geoserver

Tags: mongodb, filter, layer, geoserver

I added mongodb store and published layer on geoserver and can see feature on getFeatureInfo() but when use cql fiter openlayer do not show anything.

Can someone help me?

Comment: More details (such as source code, error messages) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this helps but Ive had a look at the geotools-mongoDB unsupported module (which I assume your using) for my own project. Ive found theres alot of problems with it. For example it sometimes performs Long or Double mongo queries with strings which returns no results and it has a habit of ignoring AND queries etc. This might be the reason you arnt getting anything back.